# Is there anyway to block a specific URL in chrome without use of an extension

Tags: google-chrome, url, blocking

Are they are programs I can use to block specific url's in chrome without extensions. Extensions can be worked around easily by killing them in task manager and I was wondering if they were any pieces of software that did the same task that could be password protected?

Comment: what if the user uses IE (on Windows) or Firefox (on *nix)? You did not specify the OS and this would be a simple workaround. If the users are not admins you could add a redirect in to the local host file which will not work if you need it on the URL level beyond the slash after the server name. Or even if they are they might not know why it does not work after you apply such a change.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the **Hosts** file and add a value for the URL followed by the local machine IP **127.0.0.1** but if there is another admin for the same PC he can change this easily..

```
www.example.com  127.0.0.1
example.com  127.0.0.1
```